# Horizontal padding between UIPageViewController child view controllers

Tags: ios, ios7, uipageviewcontroller

I am using UIPageViewController to display images that are embedded in child view controllers.

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin] forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options: options];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

ImageViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
initialViewController.index = 0;

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Everything works great but I hate that the child  view controllers are right next to one another.

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way to add padding between the child view controllers so that way they're not right next to one another.

**Something that would look more like this**:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

check UIPageViewController init method

`- (id)initWithTransitionStyle:(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle)style navigationOrientation:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation)navigationOrientation options:(NSDictionary *)opt`

you can pass your inter page space value to `opt` in `UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey`

Answer (score 18):

With Swift, you can use `initWithTransitionStyle:navigationOrientation:options:` initializer and pass a value to `UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey` in your `options` parameter to set a space between pages.

As an example, the following code shows how to implement it with Swift 2.2:

```swift
let optionsDict = [UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey: 20]

let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
    transitionStyle: .Scroll,
    navigationOrientation: .Horizontal,
    options: optionsDict
)
```

Note that the [UIPageViewController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Options_Keys) states about `UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey`:

> The value should be a CGFloat wrapped in an instance of NSNumber.

However, a Dictionary of type `[String: Int]`, as shown in the previous code, also works.

Comment: `UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey` has changed to `UIPageViewController.OptionsKey.interPageSpacing`

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Select the **UIPageViewController** from the **Storyboard**. Inside the **Attributes Inspector** there is an option for setting the **Page Spacing**.