# UIPageViewController Padding Left and Right

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

How can I implement this with `UIPageViewController`? so I can see previous and next page in active page.

[image]

I implemented this with `UIScrollView` before. Now, I want change it with `UIPageViewController`. Because I got problem with memory.

Comment: i am not sure with UIPageViewController but you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41976632/5461400

Comment: If you want to show next and previous cell's 20 pixel, then in size for item at index path just return the size as ScreenWidth - 40 - (2 x padding). Whats the issue ?? :o

Comment: @SandeepBhandari that doesn't work for `UIPageViewController`

Comment: @hezron : My bad, but why dont u use collectionView instead ???

Comment: @SandeepBhandari like scrollView, collectionView load all pages. I want use pageViewController, because this will only load previous, active, and next page.

Comment: @Hezron I don't think that UIPageViewController can handle this kind of functionality. Try to use UICollectionView. As far as I know, it is possible to reuse cells there, so there is no reason not to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal padding between UIPageViewController child view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694679/horizontal-padding-between-uipageviewcontroller-child-view-controllers)